# How should BCELoss relate to accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, torch, loss

I'm running a feedforward classifier neural network in PyTorch, in what should be a really simple test case to provide a baseline against which to evaluate more complex techniques, and puzzled by an aspect of the output, specifically that BCELoss goes to zero while accuracy on the training set remains considerably short of 100%.

This is not a question of overfitting; I am here considering only the training set, not the test set.

It is true that loss and accuracy are two different functions that are not in general expected to coincide. However, given that the training data labels are always either 0 or 1, every inaccuracy must have missed the target by at least 0.5, which should therefore raise the loss significantly above zero.

This is a sample of loss versus accuracy:

```
0.758351    0.500000
1.817934    0.500134
0.767420    0.510689
0.609878    0.516836
0.160672    0.586317
0.162658    0.617451
0.146049    0.618653
0.000277    0.583378
0.000025    0.760289
0.000000    0.872394
0.000000    0.840861
0.000001    0.870657
0.000000    0.869722
```

In other words, loss goes to zero (to six decimal places) when accuracy is still less than 90%. Yet the loss and accuracy numbers each individually look plausible.

This is the relevant section of code. Maybe I'm just overlooking something basic about the API?

```
hidden_size = 100
epochs = 1000


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(size * alphabet_size, hidden_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)


device = torch.device("cpu")
model = Net().to(device)
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)


def accuracy(model, ds):
    n = 0
    for x, y in ds:
        y = y[0]
        with torch.no_grad():
            z = model(x)[0]
        if (y and z > 0.5) or (not y and z <= 0.5):
            n += 1
    return n / len(ds)


# train the network
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for bi, (x, y) in enumerate(train_dl):
        x = x.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)

        loss = criterion(model(x), y)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if epoch % (epochs / 20) == 0 and not bi:
            print("    %f    %f" % (loss, accuracy(model, train_ds)))
```

Comment: This is a pure ML question, not a programming one. You just discovered that loss and accuracy do not measure the same things.

Comment: @Snoopy but a CE loss of 0 is only possible if targets and output are exactly equal, which implies an accuracy of 100%. It looks to me that they are computing the printed loss only on a single batch, whereas accuracy is computed on the entire dataset.